# How to push docker image to AWS ECR from jenkins hosted on EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have configured a AWS EC2 instance to run a jenkins pipeline . in that pipeline i have added AWS Push stage as below :

```
stage('AWS ECR Login'){
            steps {
                script {
                    
                    sh """aws ecr get-login-password --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com"""
                    sh "docker tag <reponame>"
                    sh "docker push <reponame>:latest"
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

i have also added all the credentials required for the below stages . also provided ECR full Access policy to given instance.

still after running the pipeline i am receiving this error :

```
Login Succeeded
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker tag <reponame>:latest
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker push <reponame>:latest
The push refers to repository [reponame]
ff1214641126: Preparing
dc9fa3d8b576: Preparing
27ee19dc88f2: Preparing
c8dd97366670: Preparing
denied: Not Authorized
[Pipeline] }
```

Comment: - _"I have also added all the credentials required for the below stages"_ - could you describe what exactly have you done?

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev i have added some like this :AWS_ACCOUNT_ID="id"
        AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1" 
        IMAGE_REPO_NAME="hffmain/hff-merchant-service"
        IMAGE_TAG="latest"
        REPOSITORY_URI = "<reponame>"

in the enviroment stage.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev and for aws username and secrete key i have added them directly in ec2 console using aws configure property

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev and i have added them in jenkins credentials manager too

Comment: Ok, so could it simply be that the credentials you use don't have push permission?

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev i am able to push image from the ec2 console but its not able to push in the jenkins pipeline.